# What is the Typescript / Angular 7 (asynchronous) equivalent to setTimeout()

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

I want to build a "typing indicator" for my chat application. I am currently trying to make the indicator disappear as soon as the user stopped pressing any key for 5 seconds.

What's the Angular way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that user's input is in a stream, call it `userTypingStream$`,

```
userTypingStream$.pipe(
   (debounceTime(5000)
).subscribe(() => this.displayIndicator = false);
```

To make such a stream:

```
private userTypingStream$: Subject<string> = new Subject();
//...
onKeyPress = (event) => {
   this.userTypingStream$.next(event.target.value);
   //... and possibly the rest of the keypress handler here.
}
```

Related topics: observables and subjects (pretty much inevitable when developing Angular apps). These seem like a good enough place to start:

https://angular.io/guide/observables

https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-subjects/

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to Angular ... how can I tell if it's in a stream / how can I put it into one?